# jQuery Extension and Stopping a setInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery extension:

```
var particleTimer = 0;
jQuery.fn.particleEmitter = function (num, wid, hei, rad, tme, rep) {
   particleTimer = setInterval(function() {
      //appends elements...
   }, 500);
};

jQuery.stopParticleEmitter = function () {
  clearInterval(particleTimer); //this doesn't stop it...
}
```

But the `clearInterval()` doesn't seem to work...

Here is a Fiddle of my complete code: http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/wtJFj/3/

Note that the "particles" won't actually move as it requires the document width...

But the timer should clear onMouseout... and doesn't...

Comment: you could try adding particleTimer to $ object so it is globally available - so `$.particleTimer = setInterval(...`

Comment: I was suggesting attaching `particleTimer` variable to jQuery object - I can see the two functions are attached - but the `particleTimer` variable is not. I assume it is declared in a closure as per standard jQuery plugin protocol.

Comment: Ah I see, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @Neuro: You **really** don't want to do that. Store it via `data` if you want, but don't put it on `jQuery`. But again, keeping track of the handles is really the caller's responsibility IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of the actual `setInterval`, your code looks fine and I can't see any reason that it wouldn't work provided you only hever have one particle emitter running at any given time.

I say that bit about "one at a time" because the first thing that jumped out at me is that you're assuming no one using your plug-in will ever call your `particleEmitter` more than once, because you're using a single variable for the handle.

I'd make maintaining that handle the caller's responsibility by returning it rather than keeping track of it yourself.

```
jQuery.fn.particleEmitter = function (num, wid, hei, rad, tme, rep) {
   return setInterval(function() {
      //appends elements...
   }, 500);
};

jQuery.stopParticleEmitter = function(timerHandle) {
  if (timerHandle !== 0) {
      clearInterval(timerHandle);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Returning the handle out of the `particleEmitter` means you can't chain, but A) Your original didn't support chaining (barring needing to return anything else, convention is to return `this` out of plug-in functions, for chaining); and B) One doesn't always need to support chaining, not if you have a good reason for returning a different value.

Side-note: I returned `0` out of the stopper function above because I tend to use this idiom in my code:

```
myHandleVar = jQuery.stopParticleEmitter(myHandleVar);
```

Obviously, that style may not be to your taste. :-)

[Live working example](http://jsbin.com/ovequb) of two emitters with the caller keeping track of the handles:

HTML:

```
<div id="container1">
  <input type='button' class='start' value='Start 1'>
  <input type='button' class='stop'  value='Stop 1'  disabled>
  <p class="target"></p>
</div>
<div id="container2">
  <input type='button' class='start' value='Start 2'>
  <input type='button' class='stop'  value='Stop 2'  disabled>
  <p class="target"></p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var handles = {};

  $("#container1, #container2").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find(".start").click(startClick);
    $this.find(".stop").click(stopClick);
  });

  function startClick() {
    var container = $(this).closest('div[id^="container"]'),
        id = container[0] && container[0].id;
    if (id) {
      handles[id] = container.find(".target").particleEmitter();
      this.disabled = true;
      container.find(".stop")[0].disabled = false;
    }
      }

  function stopClick() {
    var container = $(this).closest('div[id^="container"]'),
        id = container[0] && container[0].id;
    if (id) {
      handles[id] = $.stopParticleEmitter(handles[id]);
      this.disabled = true;
      container.find(".start")[0].disabled = false;
    }
  }

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }

});
```

---

**Update**: You asked below about stopping them *all*. That's easily done, just keep track of the handles you hand out ([live example](http://jsbin.com/ovequb/2)):

```
(function() {
  // Our current set of outstanding handles
  var handles = {};

  // Hook up our emitter function
  jQuery.fn.particleEmitter = function (num, wid, hei, rad, tme, rep) {
    var target = this,
        handle;

    // Start this interval timer
    handle = setInterval(function() {
      $("<span>click </span>").appendTo(target);
    }, 500);

    // Store the handle in a map
    handles[handle] = handle;

    // Return the handle
    return handle;
  };

  // Our "stop" function
  jQuery.stopParticleEmitter = function(timerHandle) {
    if (timerHandle !== 0) {
      // Clear the timer
      clearInterval(timerHandle);

      // Remove the handle from our "outstanding" list
      delete handles[timerHandle];
    }

    // Return a value the caller can use to clear our their
    // handle variable.
    return 0;
  }

  // Our "stop all" function
  jQuery.stopAllParticleEmitters = function() {
    var handle;
    for (handle in handles) {
      if (handles.hasOwnProperty(handle)) { // Largely unnecessary check
        clearInterval(handle);
      }
    }
    // Clear our outstanding handles. There's no race
    // condition here, JavaScript on browsers is single-threaded.
    handles = {};
  };
})();
```

Note how all of this is wrapped in a function, so the `handles` variable is private to our plug-in.

Comment: This won't actually affect the `setInterval()` though will it?

Comment: @Neuro: I don't see any problem with the `setInterval`, so I assumed you must be overwriting the handle. I just added a live working copy.

Comment: @Neuro: And indeed, from your fiddle, that's exactly what you're doing -- starting more than one emitter, and so overwriting your previous handle each time you start up a new one.

Comment: ah i see!! Is there anyway I can remove all the Emitters at once?

Comment: @Neuro: Added an example of how you can do that.

Answer (score 3):

As it was mentioned before just keep record of all timers that you set so when you want to kill them to have handle for them, here is little modification of your code

http://jsfiddle.net/qRheY/

it is not perfect but... it works (removed the sine thing because it was causing error on my browser)

P.S. if you want you can keep handlers in one array, and destroy them in one loop

http://jsfiddle.net/bnePt/

Answer (score 1):

This fiddle works: http://jsfiddle.net/7WzzH/

Maybe it is because you forgot `fn` while declaring `stopParticleEmitter` function?

Here is the corrected version

```
$.fn.stopParticleEmitter = function () {
  clearInterval(particleTimer);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Of course it won't work. You're making 12(!) iterations in `for` loop, so with your function you will clear only last interval and you will have 11 that are continue working. You have to use array at least. Or set `rep` to 1 and it would work.

Try `rep == 1` here: http://jsfiddle.net/wtJFj/5/

Comment: No, that will do nothing to prevent the overwrite of the handle.

Comment: The author didn't mentioned that he uses `setInterval` in loop. So my solution is working as expected.

Comment: @Igor: Perhaps he didn't mention it, but the bug was glaring out from the code nonetheless... :-)

Comment: the lack of `fn` isn't a mistake... It's valid for me to have a function like: `$.stopParticleEmitter()`